# Are multiple computed properties required for CSS classes in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, properties

So I have the following code and it seems like an awful lot of boilerplate and I'm there is a more ember-esque solution. Is there are way to do this without doing a computed property for each possible state?

Essentially I need to have one of three possible class names to change the color of an item on page. So for example, assuming my sales call was great vs good vs not so great it would show in a different color. I receive the state from the backend. This is what I'm doing. Is there another way?

```
App.ReturnsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  title: "Return Visit",
  titleSmall: "Create or edit your return visit here",
  isGood: (function() {
    return this.get('model').get('quality') === 'good';
  }).property('content.quality'),
  isOk: (function() {
    return this.get('model').get('quality') === 'okay';
  }).property('content.quality'),
  isGreat: (function() {
    return this.get('model').get('quality') === 'great';
  }).property('content.quality'),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ember namespace method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_computed_equal) `Ember.computed.equal` to reduce code amount, like this:

```
App.ReturnsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  title: "Return Visit",
  titleSmall: "Create or edit your return visit here",
  isGood: Em.computed.equal('model.quality', 'good'),
  isOk: Em.computed.equal('model.quality', 'okay'),
  isGreat: Em.computed.equal('model.quality', 'great')
});
```

You can also use `Em` instead of `Ember` and CoffeeScript in your app to reduce code amount even more:

```
App.ReturnsEditController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  title: "Return Visit"
  titleSmall: "Create or edit your return visit here"
  isGood: Em.computed.equal 'model.quality', 'good'
  isOk: Em.computed.equal 'model.quality', 'okay'
  isGreat: Em.computed.equal 'model.quality', 'great'
```

Please also keep in mind that `ObjectController` will be deprecated in future.

Comment: Daniel this isn't perfect but it's a lot better for sure. What will replace ObjectController in the future?

Comment: Ember.Controller. ArrayController will also be deprecated. You can use computed properties in the Model and reference model properties with controller.model.name instead of controller.name